# excel nested if formula

Tags: excel, formula

I am working on an excel file, and i am trying to use a nested if formula to achieve what i would like.

i have two columns:

A   B

condition is this:
if the value in a2=a3, then check if the minus of b2 and b3 is certain value, and if it is, put a yes, else put a no. this will iterate till the end of the excel file.

so far here is what i have. not sure how to use the excel formulas. any help is much appreciated.

```
if(a2=a3,b2-b3=5 or b2-b3=-5 or b2-b3=20 or b2-b3=-20, "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
=IF(A2=A3,IF(OR(B2-B3=5,B2-B3=-5,B2-B3=20,B2-B3=-20),"yes","no"),"no")
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using a nested IF, you could just use an AND: `=IF(AND(A2=A3,OR(B2-B3=5,B2-B3=-5,B2-B3=20,B2-B3=-20)),"yes","no")`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly use ABS function here..

=IF(AND(A2=A3,OR(ABS(B2-B3)={5,20})),"yes","no")